# Volley Multipart Request with Progress Bar

Tags: android, file-upload, progress-bar, android-volley

how to use progressbar in volly multipart request to upload images. i am using [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus) library for multipart request. my multipart request code is

```
SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String message = jObj.getString("message");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    smr.addFile("image", imagePath);
    smr.addMultipartParam("name", fileType, fileName);        
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
```

now i want to add progressbar for uploading file like this:

[image: progress bar - 1]

or

[image]